# I cant serialise a JSON with mutiple sections in it?

Tags: json, serialization, inner-classes

I have the following json that I want to serialize to send in a POST request.

```
 {
      "Details
        ": {
        "title": "Mr",
        "firstName": "Jimmy",
        "lastName": "Jameson",
        "dateOfBirth": "20.01.1994",

      },
      "meterreading": {
        "mnrr": "10234567891",
        "Longmeterread ": "12345",
        "Shortmeterread ": "23456",
        "Medtmeterread ": "34567"
      }
        },
      "otherdata": {
        "xyz": "somedata",
        "lmnop ": "more",
        "qrst ": "even more",
        "uvwz ": "last one"
      }



  I have created the following class to represent it in Visual Studio:
  {
    public class MainObjectModel
    {
        public Details Details { get; set; }
        public meterreading meterreading { get; set; }
        public otherdata otherdata { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        public string _title = "Mr";
        public string _firstName = "Jimmy";
        public string _lastName = "Jameson";
        public string _dateOfBirth = "20.01.1994";


    }


    public class meterreading
    {
        public string _mnrr = "10234567891";
        public string _Longmeterread = "12345";
        public string _Shortmeterread = "23456";
        public string _Medtmeterread = "34567";
    }

    public class otherdata
    {
        public string xyz = "somedata";
        public string lmnop = "more";
        public string qrst = "even more";
        public string uvwz = "last one";

    }

}
```

When I instantiate the MainObjectModel and then serialize it comes back as null for each class? 
I tried simplifying the class by removing the MainObjectModel part but it only serialises the first part and it doesnt have the title of the section on it?
How do I arrange the class in VS to return the json in the format above? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the `"details"` is broken :

```
# wrong
"Details
        ": {

# better
"Details": {
```